# No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox to a known managed provider native type

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Im trying to insert my data in ASP.NET but it keeps me getting error like this.
"No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox to a known managed provider native type."
How can I solve this.

This is my code.

```
 Using con as New SqlConnection(constr) 
con.open()
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_employee_information([emp_firstname],[emp_mname],[emp_lastname],[new])                                     
                                      VALUES(@emp_firstname,@emp_mname,@emp_lastname,@new)", con)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_firstname", tb_fname.Text)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_mname", tb_mname.Text)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_lastname", tb_lname.Text)   
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new", cb_new.Checked)  
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            con.Close()
                        End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: That sounds very much like it thinks you don't have the `.Checked` part in `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new", cb_new.Checked)`. Is it possible that your build is failing and you're running an old build that was missing that?

Comment: cb_new is a checkbox with a value of true or false, it depends on user if they want to check it or not

Comment: Thank you for that information that I already understood and didn't ask for. Could you answer the question I did ask now?

Comment: My build is good and no errors.

Comment: Of what datatype is the column `new` in your database? And how do you convert .NET's `Boolean` datatype (the value of the property `.Checked`) to it?

Comment: Datatype - bit. Its working now. In my current codes, i forgot to add .checked on it.